# Modulepath não aparece na aba Libraries do meu Eclipse, como posso configurar?

Tags: java, eclipse, library

Estava tentando adicionar uma library ao module path ao criar um projeto, porém não consigo adicionar corretamente pq a opção de modulepath nao esta.

Estou seguindo um tutorial.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha tela não aparece...
E a do tutorial esta assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

O conceito de modularização iniciou-se na plataforma Java na versão **9**. Desta forma, por mais que *estruturalmente* o seu projeto esteja *semelhante* ao tutorial que está seguindo, não será mostrado as informações de *ModulePath* e *Classpath*.
Obs: A versão do tutorial, certamente, exibe pois está sendo utilizada a versão *Java 10*.

Para corrigir você precisa:

1. Nesta aba **libraries** alterar a *JRE* para uma versão a partir do **Java 9**.
2. Certificar-se que **Project Facet** deste projeto está configurado corretamente:

   - botão direito sobre projeto ~> **Propriedades** ~> **Project Facets** ~> **Convert to faceted form...** (caso o projeto não esteja configurado).
   - Dentre a lista habilite o **Java** e defina a *mesma versão que configurou a sua JRE*(item 1).
3. Clique em **Aplicar**, retorne a aba *libraries* siga o seu tutorial e bons estudos.

Comment: Valeu. Vou provar isso quando chegar em casa. abs

Comment: @GustavoTeixeira, funcionou? Seu feedback é muito importante pois serve de referência para outros usuários com a mesma dúvida que você.

Comment: Vou provar...  estava usando um outro projeto e passei por cima do problema. Estou retomando essa semana depois de algumas ausente. Obrigado. Posto aqui se deu certo durante essa semana. abs